# Is $SO(n)$ actuallly the same as $O(n)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

$SO(n)$ is defined to be a subgroup of $O(n)$ whose determinant is equal to 1. In fact, the orthogonality of the elements of $O(n)$ demands that all of its members to have determinant of either $1$ or $-1$. Denote $so(n)$ and $o(n)$ to be the Lie algebras of $SO(n)$ and $O(n)$ respectively, then it can be shown $so(n)=o(n)$. This is due to the identity
$$
\textrm{det }e^X = e^{\textrm{Tr }X} 
$$
In the current problem, $X$ is a member of $so(n)$ (or of $o(n)$). Now since all members of $o(n)$ are anti-symmetric matrices which have all its diagonal elements zero, their traces are all zero: $\textrm{Tr }X=0$. This implies that $\textrm{det }e^X = 1$, so all members of $O(n)$ have determinant $1$, none of them have determinant $-1$. This further means that $SO(n)=O(n)$. But I feel like I go wrong somewhere, please someone makes it clear.

Comment: Well, it is certainly not true that $SO(n)=O(n)$, as existence of the diagonal matrix with diagonal $(-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$, which belongs to exactly one of the two groups, shows.

Comment: What I am asking is mainly the part where I went wrong in my arguments I elaborated above. I don't need a counter example for now.

Comment: Well, you wrote that you "feel that you go wrong somewhere". Having a counterexample is a sure way to get you from *feeling* that you went wrong to *knowing* that you went wrong! It is always better to know one is mistaken than to suspect that one is mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of the exponential map from the Lie algebra of a Lie group to the group is contained in the connected component of the identity element. In the case of $O(n)$, which is **not** connected, this means that **not** all elements of $O(n)$ are the exponential of something in the Lie algebra.

Comment: In general, it is not true even that all elements of the connected component of the identity of a group are in the image of the exponential (they do generate it, though, and sometimes this is good enough)

Comment: Alright, if I correctly infer from your explanation, if I write an element of $O(n)$ as $e^{X}$, then some of $X$ there might not be in $o(n)$, is that right? Therefore the use of trace identity I write above for all elements of $O(n)$ to connect with an element of $o(n)$ is probably my mistake?

Comment: Your mistake is to assume that all elements of $O(n)$ are of the form $e^X$ for some $X\in o(n)$. They are not. In fact, in this caseone can prove that the elements which *are* of that form are precisely those with determinant equal to $1$, that is, the elements of $SO(n)$.